# Google Sheets sparklines trend query using Yahoo finance data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance, google-finance, sparklines

Can someone help me write a one cell query similar to the one below but using yahoo finance data instead of google finance. This sparkline shows a trend on daily price for the last 365 days and colors the sparkline green or red depending if the current price is higher or lower than the first day from the range provided. In this case 1st day from 365 days.

I really hope this can be done as I don't want to create additional tables or tabs to store data and then produce a sparkline.

```
=sparkline(query(googlefinance(AAPL, "price", today()-365, today()-2), "select Col2 label Col2 ''", 1),{"color",if( INDEX(googlefinance(AAPL,"price",today()-365),2,2) < INDEX(googlefinance(AAPL, "price", today()-2),2,2),"green","red");"linewidth",2})
```

Here is an example of how to grab the latest price using yahoo finance.

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL","//*[@id='quote-header-info']//span"),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SPARKLINE(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1="&86400*(
 TODAY()-365)-2209161600&"&period2="&86400*TODAY()-2209161600&
 "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d",
 "table", 1),
 "select Col5 order by Col1 asc offset 1", 0), {"color", IF(INDEX(SORT(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1="&86400*(
 TODAY()-365)-2209161600&"&period2="&86400*TODAY()-2209161600&
 "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d", 
 "table", 1), 1, 1), 1, 5) < INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL", 
 "//*[@id='quote-header-info']//span"), 2),
 "green", "red"); "linewidth", 2})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this looks great except its flipped. How would I get it flipped on the x axis?

Comment: Also if possible can you provide an example how I can change the time frame to say 30 days. The timestamps I have a hard time understanding. Thank you!

Comment: @domid answer updated. for 30d you just change 365 to 30

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately yahoo finance it seems doesn't provide historical data past a certain period.
Top row is google finance. Bottom yahoo finance. 
https://pasteboard.co/IWX2wWc.png

Would you be able to help me build the same query using the free . API https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ ? 
Free API keys https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key

Comment: Actually it looks like because you're using the IMPORTHTML function yahoo may not be providing all the data as it seems to be loading the rest on scroll. Is there another way to force the entire 365 day data into the spreadsheet? Maybe a csv or json?

Comment: Hi , please accept the answer of @player0 if it did work for you and if you want to go further with more questions please ask them as different questions and not in the comment section (i.e, don't ask for more functionalities in the comments, post a question instead). This is to respect the Stack Overflow rules. Thanks in advanced :)